# Parsing csv file, getting this error "malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeeb4f4b80: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c++, csv, c++11, malloc, fstream

I am trying to parse a csv file with format as follows,

ID, Grade

There can be white spaces in between, and I do not know how many lines the file is going to have, and then I have to make a histogram of grades.

This is my code:

```
int histogram(const char filename[], int histogram[10], 
              const int minAcceptableID, const int maxAcceptableID,
              int*& rejects) {


  int numerror = 0;
  int maxnumerror = 10;


  std::ifstream file(filename);

  if(!file.is_open()){
    return -1;
  }

  int numlines=0;

  int const maxlength = 100;

  char line[maxlength];

  bool done= false;

  while(!done){

    numlines++;

    file.getline(line,maxlength);

    if(!file.getline(line,maxlength)){
      if(file.eof()){
        done = true;
      }
      else{
        return -1;
      }
    }
    enum state {ID, COMMA, GRADE, EOL, WS1, WS2, WS3, WS4};
    state instate;
    int stid=0;
    int fgrade=0;

    for(int i=0; i<maxlength ; i++){
      if( line[i]== ' ' || line[i] =='\t'){
        instate=WS1;
      }
      if(line[i]>='0' && line[i]<='9'){
        instate=ID;
      }
      switch(instate){
        case WS1:
          cout<<"WS1 "<<endl;
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate=WS1;
          }
          if(line[i+1]>='0' && line[i+1]<='9'){
            instate=ID;
          }
          break;
        case ID:
          cout<<" ID"<<endl;
          stid= stid*10 + (line[i]-'0');
          if(line[i]>='0' && line[i]<='9'){
            instate=ID;
          }

          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate = WS2;
          }
          if(line[i+1]==','){
            instate=COMMA;
          }
          break;
        case WS2:
          cout<<"WS2 "<<endl;
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate = WS2;
          }
          if(line[i+1]==','){
            instate=COMMA;
          }

        case COMMA:
          cout<<"COMMA "<<endl;
          if(line[i+1]>='0' && line[i+1]<='9'){
            instate=GRADE;
          }
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate = WS3;
          }
          break;
        case WS3:
          cout<<"WS3 "<<endl;
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate = WS3;
          }
          if(line[i]>='0' && line[i]<='9'){
            instate=GRADE;
          }
          break;
        case GRADE:
          cout<<" GRADE"<<endl;
          fgrade = fgrade*10 + (line[i]-'0');
          if(line[i+1]>='0' && line[i+1]<='9'){
            instate=GRADE;
          }
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate=WS4;
          }
          if(line[i+1]=='\0'){
            instate=EOL;
          }
          break;
        case WS4:
          cout<<" WS4"<<endl;
          if(line[i+1]==' ' || line[i+1]=='\t'){
            instate=WS4;
          }
          if(line[i+1]=='\0'){
            instate=EOL;
          }
          break;
        case EOL:
          cout<<" EOL"<<endl;
          i=maxlength;
          break;
        default:
          break;

      } 

    }


     if(stid>maxAcceptableID || stid<minAcceptableID || fgrade>100){
        numerror++;
        delete[] rejects;
        rejects = new int[numerror];
        for(int i=0;i<numerror;i++){
          rejects[i]=numlines;
        }

      }
      if(fgrade>=0 || fgrade<=9){
        int a=0;
        histogram[0]=a++;
      }
      if(fgrade>=10 || fgrade<=19){
        int a=0;
        histogram[1]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=20 || fgrade<=29){
        int a=0;
        histogram[2]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=30 || fgrade<=39){
        int a=0;
        histogram[3]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=40 || fgrade<=49){
        int a=0;
        histogram[4]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=50 || fgrade<=59){
        int a=0;
        histogram[5]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=60 || fgrade<=69){
        int a=0;
        histogram[6]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=70 || fgrade<=79){
        int a=0;
        histogram[7]=a++;
      }         
      if(fgrade>=80 || fgrade<=89){
        int a=0;
        histogram[8]=a++;
      }    
      if(fgrade>=90 || fgrade<=100){
        int a=0;
        histogram[9]=a++;
      }


  }

  return numerror;

  if(numerror>maxnumerror){

    return -1;

  }

}
```

Am i doing something wrong with the rejects array? It is define in the main() function as

```
int* rejectedRecords;
```

I store the line number in which I found an error in the csv file in rejects.

Comment: you try to delete something where there probably is nothing: `delete[] rejects;`.  Why do you use `delete` and `new`? Just dont do it. Use `std::vector` if you need dynamic arrays

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the size of the rejects array when it is first made in the main() function, so how do I use it in my histogram() function?

Comment: You seem to be making heavy going of parsing CSV - here's about the simplest CSV parser I've managed to write (and I've written a few):  https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvparse/src

Comment: btw you are assigning only `1`s to your histogram `int a=0;histogram[9]=a++;` is the same as `histogram[9] = 1;`

Comment: if you do not know the size in advance you need a dynamic array aka `std::vector`

Comment: `char line[maxlength];...for(int i=0; i<maxlength ; i++) ... line[i+1]` -- This looks like a buffer overrun on the last iteration of that loop.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  The `std::string` can grow during run-time.

Comment: You could simplify your program:  `while (file >> stid >> fgrade) {/*...*/}`

Comment: Also, at the very end of the function you have two `return`-statements. The first one will *always* end the function, and the second one will *never* be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing `rejects` into the function from code we can't see, it is hard to say with 100% certainty, but we can assume that you have not allocated the array any memory by the time you first try to delete it.

If you don't want to use the C++ standard container classes (which would be the recommended way) then you need to make sure that your `rejects` pointer is either set to `nullptr` or allocated memory before you try to delete it.